# Struggle on a lemma in Cartan's proof of existence of Haar measure

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, proof-explanation, haar-measure

I am reading Cartan's original paper

> *Sur les mesures de Haar*, comptes rendus de l'Académie des Sciences de Paris, 1940

on the existence of Haar measure on a locally compact Hausdorff topological group. There is a lemma I'm stuck on :

[image: lemma]

Translation :

> Given finitely many $f_i$ continuous nonnegative with compact support, $\rho > 0$ and $\Lambda > 0$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of the identity in $G$ such that
> $$ I_{\phi}\bigg(\sum_i \lambda_i f_i\bigg) \le 
>  \sum_i \lambda_iI_{\phi}(f_i) \le I_{\phi}\bigg(\sum_i \lambda_i f_i\bigg) + \rho ​$$
> whenever $\phi \neq 0$ is continuous, nonnegative with compact support in $U$, and $0 \le \lambda_i \le \Lambda$.

The functional $I_\phi$ is defined by
$$ I_{\phi}(f) = \frac{(f:\phi)}{(f_0 : \phi)} $$ with usual notation for Haar covering numbers and $f_0$ is a fixed nontrivial nonnegative continuous function with compact support in $G$.

This result is well-known in the particular case $\lambda_i=1$ for all $i$. For example, we can find a proof in Folland's *Real analysis*, or in André Weil's book *L'intégration sur les groupes topologiques et ses applications* (page 36) as mentionned by Cartan in the footnote.

Later on in the proof of the *Théorème d'approximation*, Cartan defines some $\lambda_i$ depending on $\phi$, so the $U$ given by  the lemma must be the same for all possible choices of $\lambda_i \le \Lambda$ (I thought at first that it was a quantifier misordering, but it would be a surprising mistake, coming from Cartan). However, I don't know, after many many attempts,  how to prove this lemma in its « $\lambda_i-$*uniform formulation* ».

Is it even possible to deduce it from the $\lambda_i = 1$ case ?
Any hint will be appreciated. :)

Comment: You can find a proof of this Lemma in Hewitt. E and Ross, K. Abstract harmonic analysis, Volume 1, page 187-189 (Lemma II). It is rather lengthy a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I have a solution.

Pick a compact neighborhood $V$ of the identity such that $\operatorname{supp} f_i \subset V$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$.
Let $K = V V$, which is compact, and choose $g$ continuous with compact support such that
$$ 1_K \le g \le 1$$

Let $\delta > 0$ be given. Define for any $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n) \in [0,\Lambda]^n$ a function
$$ h_{i,\lambda} = \frac{\lambda_i f_i}{ \delta g + \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j f_j} 1_V \in C_c(G) $$ These are continuous, nonnegative, with compact support and  $\lambda_i f_i = \big(\delta g +\sum_j \lambda_j f_j\big) h_{i,\lambda} $.

The mappings $\lambda \mapsto h_{i,\lambda}|_K$ are continous from $[0,\Lambda]^n$ to $C(K)$, the space of continuous functions on $K$. Therefore the family $\mathcal H = \{h_{i,\lambda} : \lambda \in [0,\Lambda]^n \text{ and } i=1,\ldots,n\}$ is compact in $C(K)$. According to the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem, $\mathcal H$ is equicontinuous. Moreover, as $K$ is compact and inherits the (left and right) uniform structures on $G$, $\mathcal H$ is actually (left and right) uniformly equicontinuous.

So there is some symmetric neighborhood $U$ of the identity such that $U\subset V$ and
$$ \tag{$*$} \forall h \in \mathcal H,\forall x,y\in K~,~ y^{-1}x \in U \Longrightarrow  |h(x)-h(y)| \le \delta $$
Let $\phi \neq 0$ be nonnegative, continuous with compact support in $U$, and let $0\le \lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n \le \Lambda$.
Suppose that finitely many $s_k \in G$ and $c_k \ge 0$ are given so that $$ \forall x\in G ~,~ \delta g(x) + \sum_j \lambda_j f_j(x) \le \sum_k c_k \phi(s_k^{-1}x)  $$  For any $i=1,\ldots,n$ we have
$$\forall x\in G ~,~ \lambda_i f_i(x) \le   \sum_k c_k h_{i,\lambda}(x) \phi(s_k^{-1}x)   $$   Take $x$ in the support of $f_i$. Either $s_k^{-1} x \in U$ : by symmetry of $U$, $s_k \in xU \subset K$ thus by $(*)$
$$ h_{i,\lambda}(x)\phi(s_k^{-1}x) \le \big(h_{i,\lambda}(s_k) + \delta\big)\phi(s_k^{-1}x)  $$ Or $s_k^{-1}x\in U$ and the above inequality still holds as $\operatorname{supp} \phi \subset U$. Hence
$$\lambda_i f_i(x) \le   \sum_k c_k \big(h_{i,\lambda}(s_k) + \delta\big) \phi(s_k^{-1}x)$$ This inequality remains valid for any $x$ in $G$. By definition of the Haar covering numbers :
$$ \lambda_i (f_i: \phi) \le \sum_k c_k \big(h_{i,\lambda}(s_k) + \delta\big)  $$ Summing up over $i$, using $\sum_i h_{i,\lambda} \le 1$, we get
$$ \sum_i \lambda_i (f_i : \phi) \le (1+n\delta) \sum_k c_k  $$ Since the $s_k$ and $c_k$ were arbitrary, we have
$$ \begin{split} \sum_i \lambda_i (f_i : \phi) &\le (1+n\delta) \delta (g:\phi) + (1+n\delta)\bigg(\sum_i \lambda_i f_i : \phi\bigg)\\
&\le \bigg(\sum_i \lambda_i f_i : \phi\bigg) + \delta(1+n\delta)(g:\phi) + n\delta \Lambda\bigg(\sum_i  f_i : \phi\bigg)
\end{split}$$Divide both sides by $(f_0 : \phi)$
$$ \begin{split} \sum_i \lambda_i I_\phi(f_i) &\le I_\phi\bigg(\sum_i \lambda_i f_i\bigg) + \delta(1+n\delta)(g:f_0) + n\delta \Lambda\bigg(\sum_i  f_i : f_0\bigg)
\end{split}$$ Once we have chosen $\delta$ small enough to satisfy
$$ \delta(1+n\delta)(g:f_0) + n\delta \Lambda\bigg(\sum_i  f_i : f_0\bigg) \le  \rho $$ the proof of Cartan's lemma is complete.